# How to get two <div> floating below each other

Tags: html, css, web

I want to ask how can I move floated  below another so both of them are floating on the same side but they're below each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but I solved it so, that i put both s to another  which I floated on that side.

Answer (score 2):

add `clear: right;` to its CSS...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clear: both;`.

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">test1</div>
<div class="right">test1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
 clear: right;
}
```

Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/BWvPNK

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to insert a `<br>` tag between both div. This should work.